# ¿Cómo pasar el valor seleccionado de un select option hacia otra página en ionic 3?

Tags: angular5, ionic3, ionic-framework

Buen día, actualmente estoy tratando de enviar un valor que obtendré de un select que me servirá como parámetro para mi servicio, el cual mostrará el resultado en una página. Actualmente lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

**En mi Html**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Seleccione nivel operativo</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="itemSelected" okText="Aceptar" cancelText="Cancelar" [compareWith]="compareFn">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let o of list" [value]="o">{{o.text}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

En mi archivo .ts

```
itemSelected: any;
  list: any;

this.list = [
      {text: '2 Secundaria', value: 1},
      {text: '4 Primaria', value: 2},
      {text: '4P EIB L1 L2', value: 3},
      {text: '4P EIB L2', value: 4},
    ];

compareFn(option1: any, option2: any) {
    return option1.value === option2.value;
  }
```

En la página que deseo recibir el dato coloqué:

```
this.getSelected = navParams.get('itemSelected')
```

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolví, utilicé `ion-change`.

HTML:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="itemSelected" (ionChange)="getItem(itemSelected.value)" okText="Aceptar"
              cancelText="Cancelar" [compareWith]="compareFn">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let o of list" [value]="o">{{o.text}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

Ts:

```
getItem(cod_operativo: number) {
    this.getSelected = cod_operativo;//Aquí envío el valor seleccionado
    this.getInventoryList();//Ésta es la función que traerá el servicio que necesito
}
```